# Save image to Photos app in Simulator - Generate screenshot in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uigraphicscontext, ios13

## Edit

- This appears to a bug in the Photos app of simulators running iOS 13 Beta.
- In fact, attempting to download *any image* from any website using Safari results with the very same gray "placeholder" image (below) saved to Photos.
- Also, attempting to share such images immediately crashes the Photos app (while sharing default images works).
- The very same code works (image is properly created and saved) on a physical device running iOS 13.
- Under Settings > This App > Allow app to access > Photos it says "Add only", but if I tap on that to attempt to change it, the Settings app crashes.

## Original:

How do you create an image from what is on the screen in iOS 13?

In iOS 12, this code worked:

```swift
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, false, 0.0)
view.drawHierarchy(in: view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

But in Xcode 11 using iOS 13 simulators, it generates a pixelated image with some text:

[image]

Anyone know what should be changed? Xcode 11 appears to be running the same Swift version as Xcode 10.2 (Swift 5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This bug seems fixed in iOS 13 Developer Beta 2 / Xcode 11 beta 2.

- The above code newly generates screenshots
- Images downloaded from Safari save and display properly
- Attempting to change Photo access permissions for the app in Settings still crashes Settings
- Attempting to share a previously generated corrupt image still crashes the Photos app

> Xcode 11.0 beta 2 (11M337n)
>   iOS 13.0 (17A5508l)